# Convert string month to numeric in R

Tags: r

Given an csv file as follows, which I read by `df <- read_csv('./data.csv')`:

[image]

How could I convert (or create a new column) `Month` column from type `string` to `numeric`, such as `9` for `September`, `10` for October, etc. in R?

The code below only works for abbreviation of months characters.

```
month <- c('Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug')
match(month, month.abb)
```

Out:

```
[1]  9 10 11 12  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
```

Comment: check out `month.name`

Comment: You mean by `df$month <- match(df$Month, month.name); df$month`?

Comment: yes, I think that will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach would be to convert the column to a factor:

```
Month <- factor(Month, levels=month.name)
Month
#  [1] September October   November  December  January   February  March     April     May      June      July      August   
# Levels: January February March April May June July August September October November December
as.numeric(Month)
#  [1]  9 10 11 12  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
```